# Word for species suicide?

Tags: single-word-requests

If xenocide is the word for species homicide, what would be the analogous term for doing this to one's own species? I was reading an essay on anti-natalism and thought there must be an obvious construction along the lines of suicide, homicide, fratricide, patricide, xenocide, etc. Googling has turned up nothing.

Comment: They would all have to kill themselves voluntarily. Otherwise it would be homicide. Does it ever occur ?

Comment: @NigelJ: Obviously smallpox viruses didn't deliberately kill themselves, but I'd hardly say we committed "homicide" by wiping out the species.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My fault. I meant xenocide.

Comment: Actually, I have never heard of any animal committing suicide, that I remember. They seem to have a very strong survival instinct, to me. Is it only humans that do this ?

Comment: If everyone committed suicide after having two kids, that wouldn't really accomplish anything, would it? This probably needs to operate on the concept of a species reproductive success and [fitness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_(biology)), not individual mortality.

Comment: I sure there could be a whole lot of debate what would constitute suicide for a species but that's not what I'm trying to solve. Surely there are some hypothetical scenarios that reasonable people would agree are suicide by a species.

Comment: @Nigel: Would we know (or even *care*) if one in a million *ants*, for example, were completely dedicated to killing both themselves and every other member of their own particular species? I kinda doubt it. But if we thought there were thousands of *humans* on the planet with that agenda, we'd all be quaking in our boots! (At a guess, only humans could possibly achieve such a goal anyway.)

Comment: Do male spiders mate, knowing that Mrs Spider will eat them after the nuptials ? ?

Comment: @NigelJ No: (a) there are no male spiders left who can tell the tale (b) the females ain't sayin' nothin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix 'auto-' means 'self-caused', and the word you want is '**autogenocide**'.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambodian_genocide#Autogenocide)

> Autogenocide is "the mass killing by a government or regime of a section of its own people".

Coined in the late 1970s.

Comment: You need to add references showing that this is an actual word rather than a DIY suggestion, and accepted definitions. While it might work, even such an arcane word has multiple senses.